# Google Website Translator messes up HTML

Tags: google-translate

When testing my website with Google Website Translator, I noticed that Google is changing the HTML structure of my page resulting in CSS styles not being applied.

For example, this piece of HTML (using Bootstrap):

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active">
        <a title="About us" href="/about/">About us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is changed into this format:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active">
        <span class="notranslate" onmouseout="_tipoff()" onmouseover="_tipon(this)">
            <span class="google-src-text" style="direction: ltr; text-align: left">
                <a title="About us" href="...">Over ons</a>
            </span>
            <a title="About us" href="...">About us</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, my links are being wrapped by a `<SPAN>`. How can I avoid that?

**Update**:

Google Website Translator also removes `SPANs` that are wrapped around `SVGs`, even if these elements are not a link. Very bizarre. For example:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <svg>...</svg>
    </span>
</div>
```

Is turned into:

```
<div>
    <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a native aspect of Google Translate. Best put in some CSS to fix any breakages.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix, which is specifically targeting Google Website Translator as follows.

I've changed this:

```
nav > li > a {
....
}
```

Into this:

```
nav > li > a,
nav > li > span.notranslate > a {
...
}
```